# What is the impact factor of TUGboat?

Tags: citing, fun, journal-publishing, tugboat

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_factor) defines the impact factor as follows:

> The **impact factor** (**IF**) or **journal impact factor** (**JIF**) of an [academic journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_journal) is a measure reflecting the yearly average number of [citations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation) to recent articles published in that journal. It is frequently used as a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_(statistics)) for the relative importance of a journal within its field; journals with higher impact factors are often deemed to be more important than those with lower ones.

Even though not exactly being academic journals, I was wondering what the impact factor (or more general citation metrics) of [TUGboat](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/) and other TeX related publications is, like [MAPS](http://ntg.nl/maps.html), [Die TeXnische Komödie](http://www.dante.de/DTK.html) (DTK), [The PracTeX journal](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/), [ArsTeXnica](http://www.guit.sssup.it/arstexnica/), etc.

Comment: I'd like to know the IF of the DuckBoat!

Comment: as far as i know, tugboat isn't tracked by any of the organizations that calculate or publish impact factors.  the criteria for becoming such a periodical are quite stringent, and beyond the capability of the current editorial and production crew to meet.  also more expensive.  karl berry knows the rules better than i do; i'll ask him to address this.  i don't know about the other user group publications, but suspect the situation is much the same.

Comment: Although I have seen references to (La)TeX in various places (but not in academic journals) I suspect that the only references to TUGboat and friends is among themselves.

Comment: If you do a Google Scholar search for "tugboat -marine" (to remove the real tugboats) the citation counts of any of the TUGBoat articles found doesn't exceed 100, with one cited by 92, a few in the 50 range and the rest in the 10s or 20s. And most of the articles found date back to the 1990's, with only one in 2004 and only a few later.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We submitted TUGboat to Thomson Reuters (hope I'm remembering that right) some years ago, and got (as expected) no response whatsoever. Therefore I can only suppose that TUB's "impact factor" in academic circles is zero, or, at most, epsilon :(.

Comment: Maybe the question about impact factor was too specific.  What about more general citation metrics which are not gathered by a company like Thompson Reuters?

Comment: IF rewards general interest material and penalizes specialist communities. IMHO, it also encourages "magazine style" publications rather than expert content.